# i can't show the output to the user

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I wrote this code but every time I try to show the output to the user by a `System.out.print` statement something goes wrong.

The purpose of the code is to check if the array is "palindromic".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class u {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1};
    int counter1 = 0,counter2 = arr.length-1;
    int x = arr.length/2;
    while (counter1 < x ) {
        if (arr[counter1] == arr [counter2]){
            counter1++;
            counter2--;
        } else {System.out.println(":("); break;}

    } 
    System.out.println("Bingo!");
  }}
```

Comment: Where is your `System.out.print()` statement? What error are you receiving?

Comment: i edited the question .. you can see now

Comment: Your code works just fine. What's going wrong with it?

Comment: if the the array is not palindromic it will give a wrong output.

Comment: `System.out.println("Bingo!");` is outside of the `while` loop, so it will always be executed. I would recommend declaring a `boolean` before the loop, set to `true`. Inside your `else` block, include a statement to set it to `false`. Then, after the loop, make an `if` statement that only prints `"Bingo!"` if that boolean variable is set to `true`.

Comment: Thank a lot! it worked

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the program always prints "Bingo!" it's because `break` only ends the while loop. And the "Bingo!" line is outside the while loop so it will still be called. You can avoid this by either change `break` to `return`. You can also use labels:

```
x: {
   while(...) {
        ...
        else break x;
   }
   System.out.println("Bingo!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class u {
public static void main(String[] args) {
boolean d = false; 
int [] arr = {2,9,3,4,4,3,9,2};
int counter1 = 0,counter2 = arr.length-1;
int x = arr.length/2;
while (counter1 < x ) {
    d = false;
    if (arr[counter1] == arr [counter2]){
        counter1++;
        counter2--;
        d = true;
    } else break;
     }
if (d)
System.out.println("Bingo!");
else System.out.println(":(");
}}
```